# How can I set an element's height to fill the remainder of its parent's height?

Tags: css, layout, height, html, vertical-alignment

As of now I have div A inside of div B, and A's height is set to 100% because I want it to cover everything from the start of it to the bottom of its parent div.

However, having its height set to 100% doesn't perform the way I was hoping (that it would simply span all the way from its starting point to the bottom of its parent), instead it sets its height to exactly match its parent div. Since div A starts a few hundred pixels down inside div B, this causes div A to overflow an extra few hundred pixels below div B.

Example below:

[image: Example]

The real trick is that div B needs to be able to expand vertically depending on its content, while div A continues to fill the area from its vertical start to the bottom of its parent.

Is there some other method to consider? I understand that I could use the calc unit, however, calc doesn't work on safari up until safari 6, and that would rule out a lot of mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve here but wouldn't a

```
overflow:hidden;
```

on the Div B work out?

Comment: I realized this a few seconds after I posted this. Yes, it did work. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how much content you put in div A, say, enough to justify the use of `height:100%`, the bottom of the content would be hidden. It may work out in some cases, but not an optimal solution for what the question asked.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted!

@FabrícioMatté I might have misunderstood the original post, I thought that Div A was consistently matching the height of its parent - DivB?

Comment: Yes, from OP's image, div A has the same height as B (due to `height:100%`) but is offsetted down a bit. Using `overflow:hidden` on the container (div B) will hide the bottom part of A.

Comment: I don't know, I guess I took this - 'because I want it to cover everything from the start of it to the bottom of its parent div'- to mean there wouldn't further than the bottom of the parent. I understand what you're saying though, it's a good consideration to have on the page.